# Replace all the occurrence of {.?!"><',/\|@#$%^&*~`-_=+} with a word "myWord"

Tags: java, replace, pattern-matching, replaceall

For Example:
input `String` is

```
Input =  "Hello there, How are you? Fine!! @xyz"
```

and the output would be

```
Output = "Hello there myWord How are you myWord Fine myWord myWord  myWord xyz"
```

i have tried with `Pattern` class and `Matcher` class but it only replaces one type of pattern and `str.replace(".","myWord");`

Comment: You mean all occurences of the symbols in the Curly Brackets, or the Curly Brackets as well are the symbols you wish to replace ?

Comment: i want to remove the curly brackets too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `[^\\w\\s]`

`\\s*[^\\w\\s]\\s*` :`\\s*` mean one or more space

`[^\\w\\s]` : `^` don't capture `\\w` and `\\s`

`\\w` mean `a-zA-Z0-9_`

`\\s` mean space

---

```
    String s="Hello there, How are you? Fine!! @xyz";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\s*[^\\w\\s]\\s*", " myWord "));
```

Output :

```
Hello there myWord How are you myWord Fine myWord  myWord  myWord xyz
```

To avoid any other special character , that shouldn't be replaced then just add them inside this `[]` e.g `\\s*[^\\w\\s:;\\[\\]]\\s*` , as pointed by @brso05

---

Demo

```js
const regex = /\s*[^\w\s\]\[;]\s*/g;
const str = `Hello there, How are you? Fine!! ; @xyz []`;
const subst = ` myWord `;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
String str = "Hello there, How are you? Fine!! @xyz";
    str = str.replaceAll("[\\{\\.\\?!\"><',/\\\\\\|@#$%^&\\*~`\\-_=+\\}]", "myWord");
    System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

> Hello theremyWord How are youmyWord FinemyWordmyWord myWordxyz

Comment: Why downvote the correct answer? http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down